# log4j.RollingFileAppender not compressing files

Tags: log4j, zip, rollingfileappender

How to zip backup file in log4j `RollingFileAppender`

I have following **log4j.properties** file , while exceeding size limit it is creating backup file but not zipping it.

```
log4j.appender.request=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.request.File=${catalina.home}/webapps/Sample/WEB-INF/logs/FAW_l4j.log
log4j.appender.request.MaxFileSize=10KB
log4j.appender.request.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =${catalina.home}/webapps/Sample/WEB-INF/logs/FAW_l4j.log-%d.log.
log4j.appender.request.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.home}/webapps/Sample/WEB-INF/logs/FAW_l4j.log-%d.log.zip
log4j.appender.request.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.request.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c{3}] - [%t] - %X{ip}: %m%n
```

Comment: Any chance you could let us know if you have solved it?

Comment: Hi  I have same issue with my code and @Sam suggestion doesn't give me the correct answer so would you share with me that what should I do to get rid of this problem..... Plz help me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using [logj extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/index.html) .
just configur  your RollingFileAppender configuration with the following and having the filename end in .gz will compress your logfiles:

```
<appender...>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/wombat/foo.%d{yyyy-MM}**.gz**"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: I initially dismissed this answer because my FileNamePattern was similar to Sam's FileNamePattern and my setup didn't work.  The fix is to switch to XML configuration.  For some reason, the org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender properties configuration doesn't compress files, even if the FileNamePattern ends in .gz or .zip.  At least that was my experience.  Once I changed from log4j.properties to log4j.xml, everything started working.