# Moving the log files to a backup location in log4j

Tags: java, log4j, backup

I am using log4j for logging in my application. I have set maximum backup file(size 30MB) count to 300. Since my application spits logs spuriously, it takes only a while to reach that mark. As a result, older logs were getting deleted by log4j. But I need those logs for future reference. Is there any configuration available in log4j for moving the logs to some backup location?? I don't want to increase my backup file count.

Comment: Have you considered logging into a DB and have that configured to backup to some location? Or do you need it to be files?

Comment: Logging into DB is a very costly operation. I need those files only for future reference not for any other purpose

Comment: Have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275701/log4j-rollingfileappender-not-compressing-files & http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Automatically-zipping-and-archiving-logs-td4652.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible within log4j itself.  Instead, you can create a back up process or script to move the older log files to a back up folder or location.

An answer here on SO ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683702/1754563)) gives a good base for finding these older log files using the `find` command on Linux/Unix:

```
find /path/to/logs -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The rate at which the log rotates may vary in my case. Sometimes it rotates furiously, sometimes it will be a snail walk. So this might not be a suitable solution as there will be a possibility of losing fairly new files.

Comment: perhaps a pattern match of moved log files might help example Original File  mylog.log moved file mylog.log.YYYYDDMMHH